# Swift - UI Test: Could not "Allow" permission popup on UI Test (xCode 13.3)

Tags: swift, uitest, xcode13.3

I will try to this code but could not Allow permission.

```
let popup = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
if isExists(popup) {
    let button = popup.alerts.firstMatch.buttons["Allow"]
    button.tap() //<-- *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil (NSInvalidArgumentException)
}
```

Comment: I've found more info, its did not work on iOS 12, 13 but can work on iOS 15. However this App was be back to background when a permission popup appear. Hope it help.